# How to make asynchronous HTTP request with pion?

Tags: c++, http, asynchronous, boost-asio, pion-net

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14601100/http-client-request-response-with-pion-net-c), but I'd like to communicate asynchronously using [Pion](https://github.com/splunk/pion).

I think I've figured out how to create a connection asynchronously:

```
pion::tcp::connection_ptr connection(new pion::tcp::connection(_io_service));
connection->async_connect(ep,
                          boost::bind(&http_client::after_connect,
                                      this,
                                      connection,
                                      _1));
```

Now I'd like to send a request using `pion::http::request`, but all of its send methods are blocking. How do I send asynchronously?

Comment: Well. How big is the request? Because usually requests are small enough that you build them in a buffer and then send them (async). Unless of course you want to do big uploads/long polling etc. Can you show a SSCCE of what you're trying to do and where you are stuck?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`request_writer`](https://github.com/splunk/pion/blob/develop/include/pion/http/request_writer.hpp#L30) class in Pion. As I remember it has a `send()` member function to send data asynchronously.

```
// create
auto writer = pion::http::request_writer::create(connection);

// set data
writer->write(11);
writer->write(some_buffer, bufer_size);

// send data
writer->send();
```